# How to infer $variables from ConcreteRequest?

Tags: typescript, relayjs, relay

Relay generated files from default node export of type `ConcreteRequest`.

There is also a separate type export `$variables`:

```
export type IndependentPaidProjectPageQuery$variables = {
  id: string;
};
```

However, it seems that `ConcreteRequest` has all the necessary data to infer `$variables`:

```
> JSON.stringify(node.operation.argumentDefinitions)
< '[{"defaultValue":null,"kind":"LocalArgument","name":"id"}]'
```

Is there a way to infer `$variables` just from `ConcreteRequest` using [type:typescript]?

Comment: Please add more detail. It's very hard to know what code you have that demonstates the issue, as well as what you are asking. What do you mean by "infer $variables" mean? Perhaps a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like https://tsplay.dev/wXKeQW would help.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Would Indexed Access Types solve your problem? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html